# initiate an instance from variable name and namespace in one line

Tags: php

```
$map_class_name = __NAMESPACE__.'\\'.$map_class_name;
$map = new $map_class_name;
```

Is it possible to do this in one line like this?

```
$map = new (__NAMESPACE__.'\\'.$map_class_name);
```

The above gives

> syntax error, unexpected '('

Comment: Why you want to write this in one line? Its more readable to write this in 2 lines.

Comment: I won't post it as an answer, because I don't want credit for something that uses `eval()`, but there's `eval('$class = new '.__NAMESPACE__.'\\'. $map_class_name)'();');`

Comment: @PatrickQ `eval()` is vulnerable to remote code injection.

Comment: @FabianPicone I know. That's why I didn't post it as an answer.

Comment: @PatrickQ So please dont suggest security breaking stuff ;-).

Answer (score 3):

The answer is no, you can't use `new` with string or expression.

But you can use

```
$map = new $map_class_name;
```

Since you use class from current namespace(`__NAMESPACE__`) you don't have to prefix classname, namespace will be implied.

#### Alternative solutions

You might use Reflection

```
$map = (new \ReflectionClass(__NAMESPACE__."\\$map_class_name"))->newInstance();
```

Another way is to not break line, but I guess this misses the point.

```
$map_class_name = __NAMESPACE__.'\\'.$map_class_name; $map = new $map_class_name;
```

IIFE is also possible

```
$map = (function($n){return new $n;})(__NAMESPACE__."\\$map_class_name");
```

Comment: Reflection is less performant. And the other is in practice working but not that readable.

Comment: @FabianPicone yeap, but since it's not possible to use expression with new I started to search for workarounds :) I just realised that you don't need to add `__NAMESPACE__` since you are in this namespace; tunnel-vision

Comment: I wish i had that research time like you - and `tunnel-vision` also for me ;-)